# How do you change UIButton image alpha on disabled state?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton, uiimage

I have a UIButton with an image and on its disabled state, this image should have .3 alpha.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *arrowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"];
[button setImage:arrowImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// The arrow should be half transparent here
[button setImage:arrowImage forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

How do I accomplish this?

**UPDATE**: I noticed, by default UIButton does reduce the alpha of the image on disabled state (probably at .5?). But I'd like to know how to fine-tune this value.

Comment: Did you end up find a solution for this?

Comment: I would also be interested in finding a solution for this question.

Comment: I think the answer to this question was added here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467119/avoiding-making-a-uibutton-transparent-see-through-when-disabling-it

Answer (score 21):

If setting alpha while the button is disabled doesn't work, then just make your disabled image at the alpha value you desire.

Just tested this, you can set the alpha on the UIButton, regardless of state and it works just fine.

```
self.yourButton.alpha = 0.25;
```

Comment: The problem is the prepared image doesn't know what view is going to be behind it (which is the point of alpha)

Comment: I agree it is the point of alpha, PNG supports alpha, so now whats the problem with using a stock image with alpha?
I do this all the time, in fact the only time I don't use it is when I want to dynamically change alpha for a fade effect at runtime.

Comment: Good point on the alpha PNG.  Also for [button setAlpha], I saw that and it works, the only problem is you or other code can't simply set the state of the button - you always have to remember to set the alpha and reset the alpha on state changes.

Answer (score 15):

Credit goes to **@bryanmac** for his [helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7543459/1367622). I used his code as a starting point, but found the same thing can be achieved without using a `UIImageView`.

Here's my solution:

```
- (UIImage *)translucentImageFromImage:(UIImage *)image withAlpha:(CGFloat)alpha
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectZero;
    rect.size = image.size;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
    [image drawInRect:rect blendMode:kCGBlendModeScreen alpha:alpha];
    UIImage * translucentImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return translucentImage;
}
```

Set the button's background image for disabled state:

```
UIImage * disabledBgImage = [self translucentImageFromImage:originalBgImage withAlpha:0.5f];
[button setBackgroundImage:disabledBgImage forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

---

**EDIT:**

I refined my solution further by creating a category on `UIImage` with this method:

```
- (UIImage *)translucentImageWithAlpha:(CGFloat)alpha
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, 0.0);
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height);
    [self drawInRect:bounds blendMode:kCGBlendModeScreen alpha:alpha];

    UIImage * translucentImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return translucentImage;
}
```

Set the button's background image for disabled state:

```
UIImage * disabledBgImage = [originalBgImage translucentImageWithAlpha:0.5f];
[button setBackgroundImage:disabledBgImage forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

Comment: This worked great. However it didn't use the @2x version of my image. If you use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, 0.0 ); instead of UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size) it will support retina images too.

Comment: This is a great answer! I am now using this in my app. Thanks @StephSharp!

Answer (score 7):

You need two instances of `UIImage`, one for enabled and one for disabled.

The tough part is for the disabled one, you can't set alpha on `UIImage`.  You need to set it on `UIImageView` but button doesn't take an `UIImageView`, it takes a `UIImage`.

If you really want to do this, you can load the same image into the disabled button state after creating a resultant image from the `UIImageView` that has the alpha set on it.

```
UIImageView *uiv = [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"];

// get resultant UIImage from UIImageView
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(uiv.image.size);
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, uiv.image.size.width, uiv.image.size.height);
[uiv.image drawInRect:rect blendMode:kCGBlendModeScreen alpha:0.2];  

UIImage *disabledArrow = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[button setImage:disabledArrow forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

That's a lot to go through to get an alpha controlled button image.  There might be an easier way but that's all I could find. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6):

In case anyone needs it, here's an answer in Swift:

Subclass UIButton and override enabled

```
class MyCustomButton: UIButton {

override var enabled: Bool {
    didSet{
        alpha = enabled ? 1.0 : 0.3
    }
}
```

Set the class of any button you want to have this property to "MyCustomButton" (or whatever you choose to name it)

```
 @IBOutlet weak var nextButton: MyCustomButton!
```

Answer (score 5):

Subclassing UIButton and extending the `setEnabled:` method seems to work:

```
- (void) setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled {    
    [super setEnabled:enabled];
    if (enabled) {
        self.imageView.alpha = 1;
    } else {
        self.imageView.alpha = .25;
    }
}
```

I haven't tested it thoroughly, but did find the value resets if the screen is rotated. Adding the same code to the `setFrame:` method fixes that, but I'm not sure if there are other situations where this value is changed.

Comment: I've found that sometimes this doesn't work. I think UIButton modifies `imageView` when doing its own stuff under the hood (perhaps changing between default, selected images?), and the alpha value may not persist if `setEnabled` is being called as the button is tapped (e.g., calling `setEnabled` while the UIButton is simultaneously modifying its appearance between selected / highlighted / default states).

Comment: Then override 'layoutSubviews' and call '[self setNeedsLayout]' when needed.

Comment: `-(void)setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled
    {
        super.enabled = enabled;
        self.imageView.alpha = enabled ? 1 : 0.5;
        self.titleLabel.alpha = self.imageView.alpha;
    }`

Answer (score 2):

I found that none of these solutions really work. The cleanest way of doing it is to subclass, and instead of using self.imageView, just add your own custom imageView like this:

```
_customImageView = [[UIImageview alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

Then add your custom alpha like so:

```
- (void)setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled {
    [super setEnabled:enabled];
    if (enabled) {
        _customImageView.alpha = 1.0f;
    } else {
        _customImageView.alpha = 0.25f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3**:

```
extension UIImage {
    func copy(alpha: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
        draw(at: CGPoint.zero, blendMode: .normal, alpha: alpha)
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
button.setImage(image.copy(alpha: 0.3), for: .disabled)
```

Answer (score 1):

The button’s image view. (read-only)

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UIImageView *imageView
```

Although this property is read-only, its own properties are read/write.

Answer (score 1):

A swift 4 version of Steph Sharp's answer:

```
extension UIImage {

    func translucentImageWithAlpha(alpha: CGFloat) -> UIImage {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, 0.0)
        let bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height)
        self.draw(in: bounds, blendMode: .screen, alpha: alpha)

        let translucentImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return translucentImage!
    }
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```
if let image = self.image(for: .normal) {
    self.setImage(image.translucentImageWithAlpha(alpha: 0.3), for: .disabled)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color {
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return image; }
```

Use: `[btnRegister setBackgroundImage:[self imageWithColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    btnRegister.enabled = false;`

Comment: This is a code dump with no helpful attempt at commenting on anything. Please improve this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that extends the UIButton class. No need to sub-class. In my example, button alpha is set to 0.55 if .isEnabled is false, and 1.0 if it's true.

**Swift 5:**

```
extension UIButton {
    override open var isEnabled: Bool {
        didSet {
            self.alpha = isEnabled ? 1.0 : 0.55
        }
    }
}
```