# Change alpha of imageview of UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Is there any way to change alpha of UIButton's imageview? I already tried subclassing UIButton and do below code, but it doesn't work.

```
self.imageView.alpha = 0.0;
```

I know it can be done by adding external UIImageView as a subview to UIButton but I want to know if its possible without it. Thanks!

Comment: you can try to change the UIImage alpha instead

Comment: y cant u change the button's alpha ?

Comment: @Mr.T I don't want to change alpha of button.

Comment: Afaik, the only way would be to modify the alpha of the image itself as `UIButton` resets most of it's subviews all the time.

Comment: @Igor How can I do that? UIImage doesn't have alpha property directly accessible atleast and here I am looking for some simple solution otherwise for complex solution I can add UIImageView as subview to UIButton.

Comment: Adding an imageView yourself might be the easiest way.

Comment: @JanGreve yes thats what I concluded but I wanted to give it a try asking here. Because same thing works perfectly fine with titleLabel of UIButton. This code works fine:             self.titleLabel.alpha = 0;

Comment: @sanjana >How can I do that?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084845/how-to-set-the-opacity-alpha-of-a-uiimage

Comment: @Igor thanks but I prefer to add custom UIImageView as subview to UIButton than this :)

Comment: @sanjana: you may want to select an answer and tick *This answer is useful* in order to let others know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To conclude the comments on both other answers: subclassing and/or adding another `UIImageView` is the simplest choice to archieve persistent, reliant behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

Probably a hacky way

```
for (UIView *view in myButton.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
          view.alpha = 0.5;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats the second last way :)

Comment: Also, that'd have the same effect - it'll work until the button lays out it's subviews again.

Comment: @JanGreve you are right. I don't know how come SwiftArchitect code works and mine doesn't :(
Do you have any idea?

Comment: @sanjana, that's because the selector from the slider sets the value _really_ often.

Comment: @JanGreve don't think I understood but if I set some value to slider and stop it retains the alpha i had before...

Answer (score 3):

With subclass *(will survive layout changes)*:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    if let imageView = imageView {
        imageView.alpha = 0.2
    }
}
```

Without subclass *(transient, suitable to animations)*:

```
if let imageView = imageButton.imageView {
    imageView.alpha = CGFloat(sender.value)
}
```

---

**Subclass Source Code**

```
@IBDesignable class FadeButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var imageAlpha: CGFloat = 1 {
        didSet {
            if let imageView = imageView {
                imageView.alpha = imageAlpha
            }
        }
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if let imageView = imageView {
            imageView.alpha = imageAlpha
        }
    }
}
```

Invoke with `imageButton.imageAlpha = alpha`

**Demo**

### [image: Fade demo]

► Find this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-35040233/) and additional details on [Swift Recipes](http://swiftarchitect.com/recipes/#SO-35040233).

Comment: This only works because it get's set more often than the button is laid out.

Comment: @swiftArchitect Well, its very weird because the code I posted doesn't work for sure.

Comment: @JanGreve is correct: you need to subclass for the value to be persistent

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by changing alpha of an `UIImage`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46971876/746347) for the Swift version and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22089729/746347) for the Obj-C version.

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar to this myself recently. I wanted to have a button where I could add an image as a background, and then have a semi-opaque colour overlay to the graphic so as to create a custom coloured image button type thing.

The way I found was to have:

- UIImageView (to contain the image required)
- UIView (to hold a colour with alpha=0.7ish)
- UIButton colourless/transparent.

They all have the same size, width, position and are layered in the above order.
That way you can dictate what the image will be (and its alpha if necessary), a coloured overlay on top of the image (with alpha as required), and then a transparent clickable button on top.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you please share some of your code with us?