# Avoiding making a NSButton transparent / see-through when isEnabled is false (disabled)

Tags: swift, macos, user-interface, nsbutton, nsbuttoncell

A regular `NSButton` seems to be transparent if it’s disabled.

[image]

*Image shows a Button with style 'push'*

However, I want to disable the Button **without** the transparency.

I’ve tried to programmatically set the `alphaValue` to `1.0` but it seems that the NSButtons `cell` (controlView) as well as all other subviews are already at an alphaValue of 1.0.

Also, there’s nothing like `userInteractionEnabled` or `adjustsImageWhenDisabled` (both recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467119/avoiding-making-a-uibutton-transparent-see-through-when-disabling-it)) I could use like in iOS.

How can I disable a NSButton without the standard transparency?

**EDIT**: Also a *'textured push'* button appears to be transparent:
[image]

Comment: Do you have to use a regular push button? A textured rounded button doesn't have this issue.

Comment: @rocky See my updated question above: It seems that the 'textured push' button have a little less transparency, but it’s also transparent.

Comment: Ahh you're right. I guess I wasn't looking hard enough. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the title, and will provide your own button image, you can use `setImageDimsWhenDisabled` to disable transparency in `NSButtonCell`'s image when it is disabled. Here is the code:

```
[buttonCell setImageDimsWhenDisabled:NO];
```

`NSButtonCell` is the subview of `NSButton`. But as I said, the title will still be "dimmed" a little bit, and also its background. But since image if on top of the background, you won't see the transparent background.

Another way (avoid subclass NSButton) is to have your own state tracking variable for button. When the state is disabled, dismiss any click event. Sample framework of code is like this:

```
- (IBAction)clickOnButton {
    static BOOL isEnabled = YES;
    if (isEnabled) {
        // Handle click event here...

    }
    isEnabled = !isEnabled;
}
```

This may show the highlight when clicked. You can disable highlight also. But this is not a good idea if you have many buttons. If you have many buttons, subclass NSButton is the best choice.